# Nodemon won't run in the command prompt

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, nodemon, npm-scripts

On my windows device am trying to run nodemon but this is all what i get on the command prompt

[image]

Comment: You installed nodemon localy which means it is in `./node_modules/.bin` folder. You should install it globaly using `-g` --> `npm i nodemon -g` You can try `./node_modules/.bin/nodemon index.js` but recommended way is to intall it globally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **npx** to call it like this: `npx nodemon`

If you want it to be able to run without using `npx` you'll need to install it globally: `npm install -g nodemon` (but then all your projects will share the same instance of nodemon) which depending on your use case isn't recommended.